# I keep getting this error: The extension ID MSVSAZ-ApprovedProducts-WAD11-8 is not found in the hosted service

Tags: azure-cloud-services

When trying to publish a cloud service to Azure i keep getting this error: The extension ID MSVSAZ-ApprovedProducts-WAD11-8 is not found in the hosted service.

Is there a quick resolution to this that doesn't require me to restart visual studio each time this occurs?

Comment: I got the same, its Windows Azure Diagnostics extension. In my cloud service setting in portal, I can see one in "orphan" but with a little different name. Not sure how to fix this. Restarting VS doesn't help. Do you already have a solution?

Answer (score -1):

As Khoi mentioned it has to do with Windows Azure Diagnostics.  You can either disable the Azure Diagnostics from your project
**or** you need to add the Azure Diagnostics to your Azure subscription.

Here is a link how how to configure.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-diagnostics-for-cloud-services-and-virtual-machines

To disable you would need to uncheck the Enable Diagnostics and not check it.
[image]

Comment: This didn't fix the issue for me